# Open new tab without popup blocker showing up jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to open a new tab without popup blocker showing up using the following code:

```js
(function($) {
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.et_bloom_optin_3 .et_bloom_submit_subscription').on("click", function(event) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var m_text = $('.et_bloom_optin_3 .et_bloom_success_message').text();
        setTimeout(function() {
          if ($(".et_bloom_optin_3 .et_bloom_locked_content").length) {
            window.open("my-url");
          }
        }, 1000);
      }, 2000);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you need setTimeout inside setTimeout?

Comment: I didn't write the code. I had someone else write it. I just need to get a new tab open without a popup block happening